# Audio Paused in another page

Tags: javascript, audio, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I used audio play using this method.

```
 import { ChatPage } from '.././chat/chat';
 import { Authservice } from '../providers/authservice';
 constructor(public authservice:Authservice,public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.audio = new Audio();
    this.audio.src='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-46a7f.appspot.com/o/Audio.mp3?alt=media&token=a4fa9b18-ab70-4bbc-8ae1-21639d411035'; 

   var arr=[]
   this.authservice.getNotifications(this.USERID).subscribe(dataval=>
          {
            arr=dataval;
            var user=arr.filter(a=>a.TYPE === "EMERGENCY");
            for(var i=0;i<user.length;i++)
            {
                if(user[0].STATUS === "Not opened")
                {
                  var Type=user[0].EMERGENCY_TYPE;
                  this.audio.play();
                   this.nav1.setRoot(AlarmPage,{Type:Type,key:user[0].$key});

                }
               }


          })
})
```

this audio file played.and navigate to another page.How to stop audio file in navigation(ChatPage);

I have no idea.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the variable `arr` assigned to?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I updated my code.Kindly check it.

Comment: @gerdi Can u help me..

Comment: Where is your `@Component` decorator? Also are you saying that the file is playing on navigation and that you want to stop playing it or you want to carry on playing it .. very confussed